# Run file rename text string as a VBA statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to rename files using a VBA command stored in an MS Access subform text box. It may be of note the VBA commands are generated using a concatenation formula from a database query and copied into the text box.

This is essentially the code I'm attempting to use but I get `runtime error 2434 - The expression you entered contains invalid syntax`. There may be a better way than using the eval() command.

```
Public Function BulkRenameFile()
    Dim script As String
    script = "Name ""c:\ipfimport\PE2258N2754\2620.jpg"" As ""c:\ipfimport\PE2258N2754\PE2258N2754_PH1_20141216_2620.jpg"""
    BulkRenameFile = Eval(script)
    MsgBox ("Photo Renaming Complete")
End Function
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to run a whole command in a string, instead of passing the file names individually to `Name`? ie.  `Name fileA As fileB` where `fileA` and `fileB` are strings.  Do you want to do things other than rename files using this approach?

Comment: Thanks Tim, i guess i wasn't thinking far enough outside the square, I can see this approach may just work. Only want to rename files. Will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i changed the field expression in my query which builds a rename command from a VBA code to a DOS one. I paste the complete datasheet column of DOS rename codes into a textbox. The text box is exported as a .txt file and then run as a .bat in windows DOS command shell.

example DOS rename command pasted into a textbox:

```css
rename "c:\ipfimport\PE2152N2380\*7112.jpg" "PE2152N2380_LT_T25_20140516_7112.jpg"
rename "c:\ipfimport\PE2152N2380\*7113.jpg" "PE2152N2380_LT_T25_20140516_7113.jpg"
```

The final working code:

```css
Function FileRename()
 
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim stream As TextStream

strPath = [Forms]![File Rename > Main].Text_FilePathBase.Value
strFile = "Rename.bat"

Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(strPath & strFile, True)

Debug.Print strPath & strFile

strForm = [Forms]![File Rename > Main].Text_PasteRenameScript.Value

stream.Write strForm

stream.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set stream = Nothing

Call Shell(strPath & strFile, vbNormalFocus)

MsgBox ("Renaming Complete")

End Function
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution on your own. Good that my solutions stimulated you to find a third way.
Personally I don't like this hybrid solution "Out of the code" because if everything work they are ok. When they don't work it's a mess (this is not the case). I prefer keeping every part of the code under control, especially when you need to distribute it to third parties. 
Anyway, Great:-)

Answer (score 1):

I post here two different routines, the 1st for renaming a single file and the second for renaming all files in a folder (or moving files from a folder to another). The 2nd accept a filter for renaming only a certain kind of files. They both use the FileSystemObject component (you must include Microsoft Scripting Runtime).

```
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Rename a file (returns the number of error, if any)
'--------------------------------------------------------
Public Function FileRename(strSourceFileName As String, strTargetFileName As String) As Integer
On Error GoTo Err_FileRename
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    fso.MoveFile strSourceFileName, strTargetFileName

    Set fso = Nothing

Exit_FileRename:
    FileRename = Err.Number
    Exit Function

Err_FileRename:
    GoTo Exit_FileRename

End Function
```

---

```
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Massively rename files
'--------------------------------------------------------
Public Sub MoveFiles(SourceFolderPath As String, DestinationFolderPath As String, 
                     _ Optional FileFilter As String = "*.*")

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, fld As Folder, fil As File
    Dim strDestinationFilePath  As String

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(SourceFolderPath)

    For Each fil In fld.Files

        If fil.Name Like FileFilter Then

            strDestinationFilePath = DestinationFolderPath + "\" + fil.Name
            FileMove fil.Path, strDestinationFilePath

        End If

    Next fil

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Wiz i can see the your first routine doing the trick nicely. I'm not too familiar with using the FileSystemObject component so will do some research on its merits over say using 'Name' ... 'As' .... Thanks very much, i will get back soon with my final solution.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask in case you need more info about the fso.

Comment: thanks again for your help, in the end i was able to get one FileRename(SourceFilename,TargetFilename) function call stored in a textbox to work, but if i had two or more calls in the textbox, each on a new line, i couldn't get them to run through sequentially like i wanted. So see the approach below i took in the end.