# Rename file after Unzipping it

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a sub that will unzip files from a zipped folder

```
Private Sub UnZipFile(Folder As String, FileName As String)

    Dim oSHApp, oSHFolder ' as object
    Dim sSrc, sDest ' as string
    Dim fName As String

    Set oSHApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    sSrc = Folder & FileName
    sDest = Folder

    Set oSHFolder = oSHApp.Namespace(sSrc)
    oSHApp.Namespace(sDest).CopyHere oSHFolder.Items

End Sub
```

I would like to rename the `oSHFolder.Items` once it's extracted , what would be the most optimized way ?

EDIT : the file name is not static and I cannot know it names in advance

Thank you

Comment: Rename to what? Based on what? Are the file names constant? -- Optimized for what? If speed, it most certainly won't matter what method you choose.

Comment: @Andre It's one file inside a zipped folder and I would like to rename it from potato.pdf to pizza.pdf . As for speed , Well the most optimal way

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270054/run-file-rename-text-string-as-a-vba-statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: Zip file out put rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737108/vba-zip-file-out-put-rename)

Comment: @Andre I have looked at that thread before I post a Question. And No , it does not meet what I'm looking for . If you look at Gustav answer , it's exactly what I'm looking for " oSHFolder.Items.Item(1).Name " is what I wanted

Comment: Is the file name static?

Comment: @napi15 Yes and No , it's only one file but I cannot know it name in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have only one file, it's just one line more:

```
Const FinalName As String = "YourFileName.txt"

<snip>

Set oSHFolder = oSHApp.Namespace(sSrc)
oSHApp.Namespace(sDest).CopyHere oSHFolder.Items
Name sDest & "\" & oSHFolder.Items.Item(0).Name As sDest & "\" & FinalName
```

Comment: oSHFolder.Items.Item(1).Name  , is the line I couldn't do it my self , Thank you gustav

Comment: Gustav :) it's oSHFolder.Items.Item(0).Name and not oSHFolder.Items.Item(1).Name ;) ;) ;)

Comment: To automatically overwrite any extracted file, I usually add a '20'  like this:  oSHApp.Namespace(sDest).CopyHere oSHFolder.Items, 20   Is there a way to make this final name automatically overwrite a file of the same name if it already exists?

Comment: That's what an overwrite will do. Documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/sidebar/system-shell-folder-copyhere).